# swagger-codegen-maven-plugin is not generating data-time

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-codegen

I am using `<dateLibrary>java11-localdatetime</dateLibrary>` but it is generating the code with java.util.Date and ignoring the data type `format: date-time`.

I have to use typeMapping to replace the 'util date' to LocalDate as shown in the below
configuration:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.27</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/spec.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <language>spring</language>                         
                        <output>${project.basedir}</output>
                        <modelPackage>com.generated.model</modelPackage>
                        <apiPackage>com.generated.api</apiPackage>
                        <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                        <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                        <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                        <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                        <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                        <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                        <configOptions>
                            <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                            <dateLibrary>java11-localdatetime</dateLibrary>
                        </configOptions>
                        <importMappings>
                            <importMapping>Date=java.time.LocalDate</importMapping>
                        </importMappings>
                        <typeMappings>
                            <typeMapping>Date=LocalDate</typeMapping>
                        </typeMappings>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved by using the following configurations:

```
                        <configOptions>
                            <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                            <dateLibrary>java8-localdatetime</dateLibrary>
                            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                            <defaultInterfaces>false</defaultInterfaces>        
                          </configOptions>
```

Useful links:
[swagger-codegen default interface](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/8833)